# Use vim to search text string under hex mode

Tags: vim

I need use vim to search text string under hex mode

Example file:

```
2222
1111111111111
```

After %!xxd conversion:

```
00000000: 3232 3232 0d0a 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131  2222..1111111111
00000010: 3131 310d 0a0d 0a                        111....
```

Under the hex mode, I want to search "1111111111111". However, under default xxd mode, it's not doable, because the target string is on two lines.

Does Vim provide such functionality or is there any plugin which provides functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What "functionality" are you asking about, exactly? Vim is not a hex editor so it doesn't have the functionalities one would expect from one.

There is no `1111111111111` in your buffer so it can't be searched for.

In your example, you could probably do something like:

```
/1111111111\_.*111
```

but…

- that will also match what's between the two sections:

  [image: search]
- a match is always whole, no split possible,
- that would only vaguely "work" for this specific example and you would have to add lots and lots of optional atoms to cover all scenarios.

What you call "xxd mode" is not a "mode", it's more like "I filtered my buffer through some arbitrary external command and now I have some garbage instead".

From `:help 23.4`:

```
You can now view and edit the text as you like.  Vim treats the information as
ordinary text.  Changing the hex does not cause the printable character to be
changed, or the other way around.
```

If you want a hex editor, use a hex editor.

Comment: Thanks. Above is a mini repro. In the real word (say there is a large file), there is no way to know if "\\_.* needs be put at the 11th char in advance, in Vim binary mode.
Hex editor works for sure. But I was asking if there is an easy to search text string in Vim binary mode.

Comment: And I answered "no". Moreover, there is no such thing as a "binary mode". What you have in that buffer is just text, as laid out by `xxd` with extra spaces and columns and whatnot, which makes searching for a line-wrapped string in the ASCII representation column very very hard and impractical. It certainly is *possible* to "edit" a binary in Vim with that `xxd -r` hack (which works with basically every text editor, BTW) but Vim is not a proper hex editor so you are very limited in what actual hex editing you can actually do. Use a hex editor instead.